# clojure find arbitrarily nested key

Tags: clojure, specter

Is there an easy way in Clojure (maybe using [specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter)) to filter collections depending on whether the an arbitrarily nested key with a known name contains an element ?

Ex. :

```
(def coll [{:res [{:a [{:thekey [
                          "the value I am looking for"
                      ...
                     ]
            }
           ]}
      {:res ...}
      {:res ...}
      ]}])
```

Knowing that `:a` could have a different name, and that `:thekey` could be nested somewhere else.
Let's say I would like to do :

```
 #(find-nested :thekey #{"the value I am looking for"} coll) ;; returns a vector containing the first element in coll (and maybe others)
```

Comment: Must the collections be vectors and maps? Or are other types allowed?

Comment: Can you clarify/provide a sample of what you want for a return value?

Comment: @Elogent I have only vectors, primitive values and maps (ie. no sets. the values come from a mongodb + congomongo database).

Comment: @jmargolisvt will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use zippers.
in repl:

```
user> coll
[{:res [{:a [{:thekey ["the value I am looking for"]}]} {:res 1} {:res 1}]}]

user> (require '[clojure.zip :as z])
nil

user> (def cc (z/zipper coll? seq nil coll))
#'user/cc

user> (loop [x cc]
        (if (= (z/node x) :thekey)
          (z/node (z/next x))
          (recur (z/next x))))
["the value I am looking for"]
```

**update:**

this version is flawed, since it doesn't care about :thekey being the key in a map, or just keyword in a vector, so it would give unneeded result for coll `[[:thekey [1 2 3]]]`. Here is an updated version:

```
(defn lookup-key [k coll]
  (let [coll-zip (z/zipper coll? #(if (map? %) (vals %) %) nil coll)]
    (loop [x coll-zip]
      (when-not (z/end? x)
        (if-let [v (-> x z/node k)] v (recur (z/next x)))))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (lookup-key :thekey coll)
["the value I am looking for"]

user> (lookup-key :absent coll)
nil
```

lets say we have the same keyword somewhere in a vector in a coll:

```
(def coll [{:res [:thekey
                  {:a [{:thekey ["the value I am looking for"]}]}
                  {:res 1} {:res 1}]}])
#'user/coll

user> (lookup-key :thekey coll)
["the value I am looking for"]
```

which is what we need.

Comment: very useful, never played with the zippers, I will try to have a look to handle the nested case thanks.

Comment: Forgot to check z/end in loop, so infinite loop if there is no key